# Call unmanaged code in c# and print images

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, compact-framework2.0

I need to print image in device with windows mobile 6.5 (with printer) through CF 2.0 and i have c++ header file and i also wrapped class that call unmanaged code:
Problem: I cant figure out how can i print images even if I read this document
In documentation

1. PRNAPI UINT WINAPI **PrinterLoadImageFile** (LPCTSTR pszFile);
   Description: Read the Image files. Return: PRINTER_OK: Success
   PRINTER_ERROR: Errors Argument: LPCTSTR pszFile: [in] file to read
2. PRNAPI UINT WINAPI **PrinterImage** (int nMode); Description: Print
   image. Return: PRINTER_OK: Success PRINTER_ERROR: Errors Argument:
   int nMode: [in] set the image printing mode. PRINTER_IMAGE_NORMAL:
   200 * 200 dpi Default PRINTER_IMAGE_DOUBLEWIDTH: 100 * 200 dpi
   PRINTER_IMAGE_DOUBLEHEIGHT: 200 * 100 dpi PRINTER_IMAGE_QUADRUPLE:
   100 * 100 dpi
3. PRNAPI UINT WINAPI **PrinterCloseImageFile** (); Description: Remove
   reading image. Return: PRINTER_OK: Success PRINTER_ERROR: Errors
4. PRNAPI LPCTSTR WINAPI **PrinterGetImageName** (); Description: Get
   the name of image that is read. Return: LPCTSTR: [out] the name of
   the file

and i did come with this wrapper .net code

```
    [DllImport(@"PRN_DLL.dll")]
    public static extern uint PrinterCloseImageFile();
    [DllImport(@"PRN_DLL.dll")]
    public static extern uint PrinterLoadImageFile(string pszFile); 
    [DllImport(@"PRN_DLL.dll")]
    public static extern uint PrinterImage(int nMode);
    [DllImport(@"PRN_DLL.dll")]
    public static extern char[] PrinterGetImageName();
```

part of h file:

```
//Close Image File
_DLL_EXPORT_ UINT WINAPI PrinterCloseImageFile();

//Load Image File
_DLL_EXPORT_ UINT WINAPI PrinterLoadImageFile(TCHAR* pszFile);
_DLL_EXPORT_ void WINAPI PrinterSetImageLeft(UINT nImageLeft);//ÇöÀç ´Ü»öºñÆ®¸Ê¸¸ Áö¿ø °¡´ÉÇÔ(2008³â11¿ù)

//Print Image
_DLL_EXPORT_ UINT WINAPI PrinterImage(int nMode);

//Get Image Name
_DLL_EXPORT_ TCHAR* PrinterGetImageName();
```

When I call this code

```
String path = PathInfo.GetStartupPath() + "\\logo.png";//Path to image
                NativPrinter.PrinterGetImageName();
                MessageBox.Show(NativPrinter.PrinterLoadImageFile(path).ToString());
                NativPrinter.PrinterImage(NativPrinter.PRINTER_IMAGE_NORMAL);
                NativPrinter.PrinterCloseImageFile();
```

I'm getting error in PrinterLoadImageFile (error code 1000 that mean print error).
So can any one have any clue where is my mistake.
sorry for my English .

Comment: At which line exactly the error is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way in which your call to `PrinterLoadImageFile` could be wrong is that your C# code will pass UTF-16 Unicode text, but perhaps the native library expects 8 bit ANSI. We can't tell because we don't know what `TCHAR` expands to. If that's it then you'll need to pass an `IntPtr` to `PrinterLoadImageFile` and convert to ANSI manually. Use

```
byte[] ansiBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(path);
byte[] pszPath = new byte[ansiBytes.Length + 1];//+1 for null terminator
ansiBytes.CopyTo(pszPath, 0);
```

to convert to a null terminated ANSI string, stored in a byte array.

And then copy that to a null-terminated string allocated on the unmanaged heap.

```
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(pszPath.Length);
Marshal.Copy(pszPath, 0, ptr, pszPath.Length);
```

You can then pass that on to `PrinterLoadImageFile`. When you are done with the memory, deallocate it with `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`.

The other problem is `PrinterGetImageName`. Almost certainly that returns a pointer to a string that is allocated in the library. So you'd need to declare the return value as `IntPtr`, and use the `Marshal` class to convert into a C# string. Your code is going to result in an attempt by the p/invoke marshaller to deallocate the block of memory returned by `PrinterGetImageName` and I'm sure that's not what you want.